# .TS File unable to return JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to write a function which will return below statement. The function is writen in .ts file. I am new to type script and still learning it.

```
function intitalizeApp() {    

  <React.StrictMode>
    <Loading />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
  
}
```

The problem i am facing is that  show me red underline but the same code work fine when i am putting in .tsx file.

[Please click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWaj6.png)

Can anybody point me why i am seeing red line when i am putting in .ts file or there is any other issue?

Comment: Did you look at your "problems" tab in the console (you have 5), or move your mouse over the warnings in the code to work out it out?

Comment: @Raj you need to name the file with .tsx to use jsx tags with typescript. In .ts files, those angle brackets get interpreted as being type assertions, not elements. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage

Comment: Rename file to `init.tsx` so it can use JSX.

Comment: Yes, it worked after renaming file to tsx.